# R: Making a function that prints (among other things) the name of the argument that is being used, and works within a for loop

Tags: r, function

I am trying to make a function print the name of the argument that is passed to it.

```
df <- data.frame(Q1 = 1:5, Q2 = 3:7)  #example data

explore <- function(x) {
    name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    print(paste("Summary of:", name))
}

explore(df$Q1)
```

This works and gives:

> [1] "Summary of: df$Q1"

But if I run it within a for loop it doesn't do what I want:

```
c <- list(df$Q1, df$Q2)
for(i in c) explore(i)
```

this outputs:

> [1] "Summary of: i"
> [1] "Summary of: i"

but I would like it to output:

> [1] "Summary of: df$Q1"
> [1] "Summary of: df$Q2"

**Any suggestions for me?**

I have tried a few things, this gives the same result:

```
  name <-   rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example here:

```r
c <- list(df$Q1, df$Q2)
for(i in c) explore(i)
```

The object `c` doesn't store the names of the objects with which you have created it. For example, if you do:

```r
identical(c, list(1:5, 3:7))
#> TRUE
```

You will see that `c` is just a list of two vectors, with no attributes stored telling us how it was created, so it is not possible for your function to do what you are asking, which is to go back in time to figure out how the object was created.

However, it is still possible to amend your function to get some of the functionality you want:

```r
df <- data.frame(Q1 = 1:5, Q2 = 3:7)

explore <- function(x, inloop = FALSE) {
  name <- if (!is.null(names(x))) 
            names(x) 
          else
            deparse(substitute(x))
  print(paste("Summary of:", name))
}

explore(df$Q1)
#> [1] "Summary of: df$Q1"

for(i in seq_along(df)) explore(df[i])
#> [1] "Summary of: Q1"
#> [1] "Summary of: Q2"
```